# Handle MemoryCache with worker process Shut Down

Tags: iis, cache, asp.net

I have created an API using .Net core 2.0, and I am using IMemoryCache to cache some data that takes too much time to be retrieved from database. Each Monday, new Data should be retrieved from the database and saved in cache; When I published the  API on IIS webserver 2016, I realized that data is saved in cache only for some minutes, then it will be retrieved from database again; After searching for days trying to solve this issue, I discovered that the worker process on IIS will last only for 20 minutes, and when it shuts down, data is being cleared from cache, that's why it is being retrieved again from database;
Now my question is the below:

1. How much the **IDLE Time-out** should be equal to? Is 10,080 minutes = 1 week a safe value?
2. I realized also that recycling has a time value to reset after (**Regular Time Interval** = 1740 by default), how should it be changed?
3. Is there anything else needed to make my cache last for one week before being recycled?

Yes I am beginner in publishing on webservers, but I am ready to learn IIS tricks!

Comment: The true question is 1) how much data you should cache. 2) how long you should cache them. 3) where such data should be cached. If you want to reduce access to your database, and also work well with IIS application pool shutdown/recycle, your current design (of caching everything in memory) has flaws. IIS shuts down/recycles the worker processes (as well as .NET Core processes) because it tries to keep them healthy and of small enough footprint. So instead of changing IIS settings, you might consider using a file based cache, or Redis. More like a design question, and opinion based.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for your reply, 1) For the moment max 1MB data should be cached; 2) Caching should be max for one week and in memory; Concerning Redis, if worker process shuts down, then data won't be cleared from cache?